# squid, TLS connection between browser and proxy

Tags: proxy, squid, http-proxy

I have a `squid` instance (v4.6) on a public address `A.B.C.D` setup with `basic_auth` (`ldap` backend). This works over **unencrypted** port, say `8080`, using `http_port A.B.C.D:8080`. I'm trying to fiugre out how to secure connections to my `squid` over the insecure Internet (only authenticated users should be allwed to use the `proxy`). I'm using PROXY in the current Firefox 75 to test the connection.

I tried many things, including:

```
https_port A.B.C.D:8443 tls-cert=/path/to/cert tls-key=/path/to/key
SLL_ports 8443
```

When I enter this port to the Firefox PROXY settings, nothing happens, no `basic_auth` prompt, is shown, nothing.

Logs say:

```
1587588731.539      0 F.G.H.I NONE/000 0 NONE error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -
```

Is it possible to secure `basic_auth` (using TLS) when using PROXY? Sending unencrypted passwords over the Internet is simply wrong. I started to think about putting `nginx` with TLS and `basic_auth` in front of `squid`, but I do not know yet if this is possible.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still interested, in FreeBSD.

```
    http_port 192.168.2.1:3128
    http_port 192.168.2.1:8888 intercept # ipfw fwd sends here http

# ipfw fwd 443 sends here
    http_port 192.168.2.1:8443 intercept ssl-bump cert=/usr/local/etc/squid/ssl/myCA.crt key=/usr/local/etc/squid/ssl/myCA.key generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=16MB
```

and dynamic cert generation

```
    sslcrtd_program /usr/local/libexec/squid/security_file_certgen -s /var/log/squid/ssl_db -M 16MB
```